# ln: /usr/bin/php: Operation not permitted OSX 10.11

Tags: php, macos, laravel, phpunit, symlink

I use PHPStorm on OSX with PHPUnit and Laravel.

When I go inside my project from the **PHPStorm console** and type:

```
$ php --version

PHP 5.5.29 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2015 00:26:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

$ which php

/usr/bin/php
```

From my terminal:

```
$ php --version

PHP 5.6.16 (cli) (built: Nov 27 2015 21:37:15) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

$ which php

/usr/local/php5/bin/php
```

The above I installed.  I have edited my `PATH` to use it.

Now I want to change the PHP version inside my PHPStorm.

I tried editing composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.16",
```

and then running update:

```
$ composer update

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.6.16 but your PHP version (5.5.29) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I also tried to create a symbolic link .

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/php5/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

It fails with:

```
ln: /usr/bin/php: Operation not permitted
```

I am not sure what to do.  I would like to update Php to 5.6.16.

Comment: The require line with composer states the dependency.  As in, this project needs this version, but you don't use composer to install php  (not yet at least).

Comment: The link is most likely failing because you already have something at the source.  What does $ readlink -e /usr/bin/php currently show?

Answer (score 3):

It appears you have at least two versions of Php installed.

Try changing the [interpreter path](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/configuring-local-php-interpreters.html) within PhpStorm.

File->settings->languages & frameworks->interpreter ...

Comment: There i have set my php interpreter as 5.6.16

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya, so to confirm the interpreter path has no effect on the console?

Comment: Is there no way to edit the console environment within PhpStorm settings?  If not try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Comment: Hey Actually the problem was , i had 3 PHP versions , I added one PHP path to .bash_profile in my home . now it is working .  :) :)